# Ошибка "Unsupported expression of type 'Constant'. Did you miss the member access prefix in the expression?" С#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

У меня при работе программы появляется такая ошибка. "Unsupported expression of type 'Constant'. Did you miss the member access prefix in the expression?" При сборке проекта ее нет.
Я пытаюсь привязать кнопки в WPF с командами ReactiveCommand

**Вот код представления**

```
public partial class Home : ReactiveWindow<HomeViewModel>
{
    public Home()
    {
        DataContext = ViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(disposable =>
        {
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.nameUser, x => x.TextBlock1.Text);
           
            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.Message, x => MessageButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x=> x.Button1Text, x=> MessageButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.EditInformation, x => EditInformationButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button2Text, x => EditInformationButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.OrderNewProject, x => OrderNewProjectButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button3Text, x => OrderNewProjectButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.ViewProgress, x => ViewProgressButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button4Text, x => ViewProgressButton.Content);
        });
    }
}
```

**Вот код моей ViewModel**

```
 public class HomeViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public  ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ViewProgress {  get; set; }
    public  ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Message { get;  }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> EditInformation { get;  }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OrderNewProject { get; }
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        var PublicDataConnecton = new DataConnecton();
        GlobalData.name = PublicDataConnecton.GetUserName(GlobalData.login, GlobalData.password) ;
        GlobalData.id =  Convert.ToInt32(PublicDataConnecton.GetUserId(GlobalData.login, GlobalData.password)) ;
        nameUser = GlobalData.name;
        if (GlobalData.id >9999)
        { 
            Button1Text = "Написать сообщение";
            Button2Text = "Редактировать личную информацию";
            Button3Text = "Заказать новый проект";
            Button4Text = "Ход разработки проектов";
        }
        ViewProgress = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        { Console.WriteLine("ss"); });
        Message = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        { Console.WriteLine("ss"); });
        EditInformation = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        { Console.WriteLine("ss"); });
        OrderNewProject = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        { Console.WriteLine("ss"); });
    }

    
    [Reactive]
    public string nameUser { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public string Button1Text { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public string Button2Text { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public string Button3Text { get; set; }
    [Reactive]
    public string Button4Text { get; set; }
}
```

В работе используется Фреймворк ReactiveUI. А ошибки в строчках

```
            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.Message, x => MessageButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x=> x.Button1Text, x=> MessageButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.EditInformation, x => EditInformationButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button2Text, x => EditInformationButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.OrderNewProject, x => OrderNewProjectButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button3Text, x => OrderNewProjectButton.Content);

            this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.ViewProgress, x => ViewProgressButton);
            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Button4Text, x => ViewProgressButton.Content);
```

Comment: Чего только не придумают. В какой строчке ошибка? Отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Очередной фреймоворк для MVVM. Как хоть называется? И в какой строке ошибка?  Лучше бы писали самостоятельно безо всяких приблуд, хоть разобрались бы как работают привязки и проч.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так не делается

```
this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.EditInformation, x => EditInformationButton);
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x=> x.Button1Text, x=> MessageButton.Content);
```

так делается

```
this.BindCommand(this.ViewModel, x => x.EditInformation, x => x.EditInformationButton);
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, x=> x.Button1Text, x=> x.MessageButton.Content);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]